# header en PHP como cambiar la etiqueta title y meta descripciones del head dependiendo de cada pagina?

Tags: php, html, seo, meta-tags

Hola una consulta eh creado una pequeña aplicacion web en php esta no tiene muchas paginas. Ahora lo que hice es crear una plantilla llamada header.php la misma que llamo en cada una de las paginas el problema es que como uso la misma cabecera la etiqueta title tiene el mismo nombre para todas las paginas. Cual seria la forma mas facil de hacer que la etiqueta
 `<title></title>`
tome el nombre de su respectiva pagina.
Ahora que lo pienso mas a fondo como se haria para cambiar las las meta etiquetas

```
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="keywords" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">
```

dependiendo de la pagina en una aplicación web hecha en PHP. Lo siento si la pregunta es fácil, soy nuevo en PHP y lo estoy aprendiendo gracias.

Comment: Tu pregunta está basada en opiniones, ten en cuenta que la solución "más facil" es subjetiva. Revisa [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Esto debe funcionar:

Primero cambia lo que tienes por:

```html
 <meta name="description" content="<?php if (isset($meta_description)) {echo $meta_description;}
else {echo "Descripción por default";} ?>">
  <meta name="keywords" content="<?php if (isset($meta_keywords)) {echo $meta_keywords;}
else {echo "Keywords por default";} ?>">
  <meta name="author" content="<?php if (isset($meta_author)) {echo $meta_author;}
else {echo "Autor por default";} ?>">
```

Y luego en cada página vas estableces el valor de las variables es decir si es la página contacto dentro de tu archivo php de preferencias hasta arriba pones:

```php
$meta_keywords = 'palabra1, palabra2, palabra3, palabra4, etc';
$meta_author = 'Descripcion autor';
$meta_description = 'Descripcion contacto';
```

Esto hará que busque en cada página, si están declaradas las variables las coloca, en caso de que no existan pone el valor por default que establezcas.

Comment: Hola gracias lo voy a probar y para la etiqueta de title como podria hacerlo?

Comment: Exactamente igual por un <title><?php if (isset($meta_title)) {echo $meta_title;}
else {echo "Tu sitio Web";} ?></title> y abajo estableces la variable $meta_title = 'Contacto'; o incluso mejor puedes poner algo como:  <title>Tu sitio web | <?php if (isset($meta_title)) {echo $meta_title;}
else {echo "Tu sitio Web";} ?></title>

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo lo voy a probar.

Comment: Espero que te funcione (: